# Why do I get an abstract error even though the subclass defines the abstract function?

Tags: delphi, function, dynamic, call

I have a class `Packet` with an abstract method `getID`:

```
Type
  Packet = class
    ...
    function getID() : Integer;virtual;abstract;
    class procedure writePacket(par0 : Packet; par1 : TIdTCPConnection);
    ...
implementation 

class procedure Packet.writePacket(par0 : Packet; par1 : TIdTCPConnection);
// par1 is a TCP connection used to send data through the network; 
begin
  par1.writeInteger(par0.getID());
  //some code following 
end;
```

I have the following subclass:

```
type
  PacketTest = class(Packet)
    ...
    function getID() : Integer;
    ...

function PacketTest.getID():Integer;
begin
  result := {some value individual for each subclass}
end;
```

Now I call the superclass's class procedure `writePacket` with a subclass of packet as `par0`, which should then call the subclass's function `getID`.
Instead it calls the superclass's function `getID` and (of course) throws an abstract error.

I want it to dynamically call the subclass's function `getID`, which should never cause a problem because `par0` is always a subclass of `Packet` since `Packet` itself is abstract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration of `getID` in the subclass must have the override keyword:

```
type
  PacketTest = class(Packet)
    function getID: Integer; override;
  end;

function PacketTest.getID: Integer;
begin
  Result := {some value individual for each subclass}
end;
```

Comment: @User, you had to ignore multiple warnings before you got to this error. First, the compiler warned you that the subclass function was hiding the virtual method of the base class. Second the compiler warned you that you were creating an instance of a class that had abstract methods. Never disable or ignore compiler warnings.